# Web API PUT example

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, put

Can someone point me to or show me a proper PUT example?

Everything I've come across has been inconsistent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thinking that you are already in controller....

```
[HttpPut]
public HttpResponseMessage MyPutAction(myModelType MyModel) 
{
    ....
    // here is some code that will update the record and return it as part of HttpResponseMessage 
    ....
```

or

```
public HttpResponseMessage Put(myModelType MyModel) ....
```

In the second example MVC framework knows that this is [Put] based on the Method name. So you don't need to decorate it with  [HttpPut]

or

```
public HttpResponseMessage PutMyModel(myModelType MyModel) ....
```

Sounds stupid but works just like the one above. Again, MVC framework knows that this is [Put] based on the Method name, because it starts with "Put".